# In Mysql How to fetch distinct row value from a column1 and sum(column 2 row value) group by invoice number

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating monthly bill report, each bill will contain multiple items, each item has different gst percentage.

I want to get the total gst_amount based on gst percentage group by invoice number

```
SELECT SUM( lgb_gst_amt ) FROM  `lg_bill` WHERE lgb_gst IN (SELECT DISTINCT lgb_gst FROM  `lg_bill`)
```

Table Structure

```
lgb_invoice | lgb_gst | lgb_gst_amt
-----------------------------------
1138        | 12.00   | 1.80
1138        | 12.00   | 3.00
1138        | 10.00   | 3.00
1138        | 10.00   | 12.50
```

Expected output

```
lgb_invoice | lgb_gst | lgb_gst_amt
-----------------------------------
1138        | 12.00   | 4.80
1138        | 10.00   | 15.50
```

Comment: GROUP BY all fields you want to group by; in this case invoice and gst.

Answer (score 2):

Your subquery doesn't make any sense as it will always be true for all rows.

It looks like you just want to group by `lgb_invoice` and `lgb_gst` and sum `lgb_gst_amt`.

```
SELECT lgb_invoice,
       lgb_gst,
       sum(lgb_gst_amt) lgb_gst_amt
       FROM lg_bill
       GROUP BY lgb_invoice,
                lgb_gst;
```